# How to divide a 2D shape in patches of approx equal size in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a 2D matrix of zeros and ones, where the ones indicate a convex figure

[image: my starting figure]

I now want to divide this figure (that is the elements of value 1) in nonoverlapping patches of equally the same size, as in this figure

[image: the type of division that I am after]

Do you have any suggestion? I could go for `mat2cell` and have just rectangles, and keep the rectangles with at least one value 1 in them, but I would prefer a more equal division.

Comment: This problem is more a mathematical / classification problem, maybe go to [math.st](https://math.stackexchange.com) ?

Comment: You can triangulate the region.

Answer (score 0):

For similar problems, I often use a method called 'orthogonal recursive bisection'.
An example of what it does with your circle is in the picture.

As the name suggests, the method divides subdomains into two smaller subdomains,
until the total number of subdomains is the desired value.

My implementation for your case is

```
function array = ORB(array,nparts)
%
% array = ORB(array,nparts)
%
% Divide the nonzeros of array into nparts equally large,
% approximately square parts.
%

% convert true/false array into 0/1:
ar    = array; array = zeros(size(ar)); array(ar)  = 1;

% initialize subdivision-admin
istart = 1; iend = nparts; values = 1;
last_value = max(values);

% Divide up the parts that need dividing up
while length(values) < nparts
    new_istart = []; new_iend = []; new_values = [];
    for i = 1:length(values)
        if iend(i) > istart(i)
           disp(sprintf('Current values %d should eventually be split into domains %d-%d',values(i),istart(i),iend(i)))
           last_value = last_value + 1;
           new_istart = [new_istart, istart(i),                                    istart(i) + floor((iend(i)-istart(i)+1)/2)];
           new_iend   = [new_iend,   istart(i) + floor((iend(i)-istart(i)+1)/2)-1, iend(i)];
           new_values = [new_values, values(i),                                    last_value];
           n = length(new_values);
           disp(sprintf('Current values %d should now be split into domains %d and %d, in ratio %d:%d\n', ...
                               values(i), new_values(n-1:n),new_iend(n-1:n)-new_istart(n-1:n)+1));
           array = Split(array,new_values(n-1:n),new_iend(n-1:n)-new_istart(n-1:n)+1);
        else
           disp(sprintf('Domain %d is done\n',values(i)))
           new_istart = [new_istart, istart(i)];
           new_iend   = [new_iend,   iend(i)];
           new_values = [new_values, values(i)];
        end
    end
    iend   = new_iend; istart = new_istart; values = new_values;
end
for i = 1:nparts
   disp(sprintf('Part %d has %d points',i,length(find(array==i))))
end
close all
pcolor(array)
```

which needs the function Split:

```
function array = Split(array,parts,sizes)
%
% array = Split(array,parts,sizes)
%
% Change some of the values of array which are now equal to parts(1) into the value parts(2).
% At the end, the ratio
%   length(find(array==parts(1))) : length(find(array==parts(2)))
% should be
%                        sizes(1) : sizes(2)
%

% Calculate sizes of each patch
[i,j] = find(array==parts(1));
npoints = size(i,1); sizes = npoints * sizes/(sizes(1)+sizes(2));


imin = min(i); imax = max(i); jmin = min(j); jmax = max(j);
nmin = 0; nmax = npoints;
if jmax-jmin>imax-imin
   % divide domain in (j < jmid) and (jmid <= j)
   while jmax > jmin + 1
      jmid = (jmax + jmin)/2; n_this = size(find(j<jmid));
      if n_this < sizes(1)
         jmin = jmid; nmin = n_this;
      else
         jmax = jmid; nmax = n_this;
      end
   end
   i = i(j>=jmid); j = j(j>=jmid);
else
   % divide domain in (i < imid) and (imid <= i)
   while imax > imin + 1
      imid = (imax + imin)/2; n_this = size(find(i<imid));
      if n_this < sizes(1)
         imin = imid; nmin = n_this;
      else
         imax = imid; nmax = n_this;
      end
   end
   j = j(i>=imid); i = i(i>=imid);
end

% Change the values in array
array(sub2ind(size(array),i,j)) = parts(2);
```